# Testing Play Enumeratee

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play Enumeratee/Enumerator to send browser events. My events are case classes which will be serialized to JSON. I have code similar to this:

```scala
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumeratee, Enumerator, Iteratee}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
implicit val ex = ExecutionContext.global


case class SomeClass(a: String, b: String, c: List[String])

val someEnumerator: Enumerator[SomeClass] = Enumerator.apply(
  SomeClass("a", "b", List("a", "b", "c")),
  SomeClass("s", "a", Nil),
  SomeClass("g", "g", Nil),
  SomeClass("a", "T", List("a", "1", "c")))

val filtering: Enumeratee[SomeClass, SomeClass] = Enumeratee.filter[SomeClass](sc => sc.c.nonEmpty)

val toJson: Enumeratee[SomeClass, String] =
  Enumeratee.map[SomeClass] {
    sc =>
      import org.json4s._
      import org.json4s.native.Serialization
      implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
      Serialization.write(sc)
  }

val jsonStream: Enumerator[String] = someEnumerator &> filtering &> toJson
```

How can I get result and test `filtering`, `toJson` and `jsonStream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to run the `Enumerator` through an `Iteratee` to collect the results, and then make assertions on what the result should be. You can use `Iteratee.getChunks` to feed an `Enumerator[SomeClass]` into a `List[SomeClass]`.

```
// test filtering
val filterResult: Future[List[SomeClass]] = someEnumerator &> filtering |>>> Iteratee.getChunks

// Using the specs2 dsl just to illustrate my point.
// This won't compile as-is, as `filterResult` is a `Future`, so we need to use
// await to unwrap the `Future` and make our assertions. In specs2 I think
// you can use filterResult.await..., but I'm not 100% sure.
// You can also use Await.result(filterResult, Duration.Inf)
filterResult.forall(_.c.nonEmpty) must beTrue

// test json
val jsonResult: Future[List[String]] = someEnumerator &> toJson |>>> Iteratee.getChunks

// Use some assertion to match the JSON structure you get back.
```